# How to setup the grafana agent flow to scrape data and send it to Grafana Mimir?

Tags: grafana, grafana-agent, grafana-mimir

I have installed a **grafana agent flow** agent to collect the OS metrics data from a linux machine. However, I understood that Grafana agent flow cannot collect and expose the OS metrics, so installed the node exporter in the linux machine. Now, how can I configure the node-exporter to the grafana-flow-agent to send the data to grafana-mimir.

grafana-agent-flow is in .river language.

Also, **could you please let me know how to setup grafana mimir as open source ? The overall idea is to do the OS monitoring using Grafana-agent-flow and Grafana-Mimir.**

There is no document which describes visually about this setup